# Integrate map in phpBB where users can add locations, areas, paths

Tags: collaboration, maps, phpbb

I run a phpBB-based forum. I'd like to add an ability for registered users to add some locations, areas, paths to the common map (Google Maps, OSM, …) with object name/description.

Can someone suggest something like this?